# How to check if a file is an image type in C++?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, c++-cli

I would like to check if a file that I have in my hard disk is an image before using it.

I'm using C++/Cli

```
OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK ) {
     Bitmap^ PreviewImage = gcnew Bitmap(openFileDialog1->FileName); //If File is not an image this will crash.

}
```

as I commented in the line, if the file is not an image that will generate an error, how do I check if the file is an image before hand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By catching the exception.

.Net does not have any `TryRead` method that would return false instead of throwing an exception.

You could check the extension, but a `.png` file can also be am invalid image.
(However, you should set the `Filter` to discourage users from selecting other file types in the first place)

Comment: would you mind showing an example catching this exception? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you asking how to use a `catch` block?

Comment: haha oh yeaa my bad, I  thought about something else. ;D That is clear to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would add a filter to OpenFileDialog so the user can select only images.

```
OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
openFileDialog1->Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF" ;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx

However, you still need to check for errors when you try to open the file, because the user can always try to type an invalid file name in the dialog's text box.

> Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to
>   build bigger and better idiot-proof programs, and the universe trying
>   to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the universe is winning.
>
> Rich Cook

Comment: @AJG85 I figured out that he still needs to check for error. I edited the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

Convention usually dictates that file contents is described by the extension name.  If I was you I'd do some basic checking to make sure you're only allowing .bmp, .jpeg, .jpg, .gif, etc.  Also as mentioned by another answer you should make sure to catch the exception and you can tell the user that an error occurred there.

You can do something like this:

```
OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK ) {
     try
     {
         Bitmap^ PreviewImage = gcnew Bitmap(openFileDialog1->FileName); //If File is not an     image this will crash.
     }
     catch(Exception ^ex)
     {
           //do something with the exception here
     }
}
```